# Do not display file in browser when using Google Cloud Storage: ALWAYS DOWNLOAD

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, google-cloud-storage

I just started using Google Cloud Storage with a Rails 3 app.  I am able to successfully upload the file to my bucket using Carrierwave, but I want the file to ALWAYS DOWNLOAD when the link is clicked on and NEVER render directly in the browser.

I know that with Dropbox you can simply add "?dl=1" to the end of the download link and it will always download.  Does Google Cloud Storage have any such URL convention? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some further research it looks like you have to modify the HTTP header yourself for Content-Disposition.

https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-headers#contentdisposition